# Excel - Separate values from column into two columns

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have two columns that look like so:

```
Data A  | Data B
-----------------
Type1   |  23
Type2   |  19
Type1   |  3
Type2   |  9
Type1   |  9
```

I would like to separate it into:

```
Type1 | Type2
-------------
23    |  19
3     |  9
9     |
```

How can this be generally done in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...meanwhile in Google Sheets...

```
={"Type1","Type2";{FILTER(B1:B,A1:A="Type1"),FILTER(B1:B,A1:A="Type2")}}
```

[image: 0]

---

```
={"Type1","Type2"; 
  ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
  JOIN("♦",FILTER(B1:B,A1:A="Type1"))&"♥"&
  JOIN("♦",FILTER(B1:B,A1:A="Type2")),"♥")),"♦")))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This works great if the two types have equal amount of values, which mine unfortunately doesn't... I glanced over this and apologize for not having mentioned it. :(

Comment: You're brilliant. Thank you so much for the help!